# How to send shell script output in a tablular form and send the mail

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am a shell script which will give few lines as a output. Below is the output I am getting from shell script. My script flow is like first it will check weather we are having that file, if I am having it should give me file name and modified date. If I am not having it should give me file name and not found in a tabular form and send email. Also it should add header to the output.

```
CMC_daily_File.xlsx Not Found
CareOneHMA.xlsx Jun 11
```

Output

```
File Name             Modified Date 
CMC_daily_File.xlsx   Not Found
CareOneHMA.xlsx       Jun 11
```

UPDATE

sample of script

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -e /saddwsgnas/radsfftor/coffe/COE_daily_File.xlsx ]; then
    cd /sasgnas/radstor/coe/
    ls -la COE_daily_File.xlsx | awk '{print $9, $6"_"$7}'
else
    echo "CMC_COE_daily_File.xlsx Not_Found"
fi
```

Output

```
CMC_COE_daily_File.xlsx Jun_11
```

Comment: `yourscript.sh | { printf 'File Name\tModified Date\n'; sed -E $'s/ ([^ ]+ [^ ]+)$/\t\\1/'; } | column -s $'\t' -t | sendmail your@email` ?

Comment: @Fravadona , what is the column here. I am getting error as ksh: column:  not found.

Comment: That's a Linux utility for formatting outputs

Comment: On what basis it will split it into two colums

Comment: I replaced the second space (starting from the right) by a tab; then I told `column` to format on tabs

Comment: @Fravadona, I have updated the question with my sample script and output. Could pls have a look and check what I am missing.

Comment: what OS are you using for you to parse `ls -l` to get the modification date?

Answer (score 0):

I thought I might offer you some options with a slightly modified script.  I use the **stat** command to obtain the file modification time in more expansive format, as well as specifying an **arbitrary, pre-defined, spacer character** to divide the column data.  That way, you can focus on displaying the content in its original, untampered form.  This would also allow the formatted reporting of filenames which contain spaces without affecting the logic for formatting/aligning columns.  The column command is told about that spacer character and it will adjust the width of columns to the widest content in each column.  *(I only wish that it also allowed you to specify a column divider character to be printed, but that is not part of its features/functions.)*

I also added the extra AWK action, on the chance that you might be interested in making the results stand out more.

```
#!/bin/sh

#QUESTION:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74571967/how-to-send-shell-script-output-in-a-tablular-form-and-send-the-mail

SPACER="|"

SOURCE_DIR="/saddwsgnas/radsfftor/coe"
SOURCE_DIR="."

{
    printf "File Name${SPACER}Modified Date\n"
    #for file in COE_daily_File.xlsx
    for file in test_55.sh awkReportXmlTagMissingPropertyFieldAssignment.sh test_54.sh
    do
        if [ -e "${SOURCE_DIR}/${file}" ]; then
            cd "${SOURCE_DIR}"
            #ls -la "${file}" | awk '{print $9, $6"_"$7}'
            echo "${file}${SPACER}"$(stat --format "%y" "${file}" | cut -f1 -d\. | awk '{ print $1, $2 }' )
        else
            echo "${file}${SPACER}Not Found"
        fi
    done
} | column -x -t -s "|" |
awk '{
    ### Refer to:
    # https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html
    # https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-48/
    if( NR == 1 ){
        printf("\033[93;3m%s\033[0m\n", $0) ;
    }else{
        print $0 ;
    } ;
}'
```

Without that last awk command, the output session for that script was as follows:

```
ericthered@OasisMega1:/0__WORK$ ./test_55.sh
File Name                                         Modified Date
test_55.sh                                        2022-11-27 14:07:15
awkReportXmlTagMissingPropertyFieldAssignment.sh  2022-11-05 21:28:00
test_54.sh                                        2022-11-27 00:11:34
ericthered@OasisMega1:/0__WORK$
```

With that last awk command, you get this:

[image]